# Need to synchronize two classes

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have two classes A & B. Both are calling each other and having their own locks. I am getting a deadlock in one particular scenario. Here is the sample code.

```
class A : Interface1, Interface2
{
    private B _bInstance = new B(); 
    private object _aSync = new object();

    private static A Instance;
    private A(){}

    public GetInstance()
    {
        if (Instance == null)  Instance = new A();
        return Instance;
    }

    void Method1()
    {
        lock(_aSync)
        {
            _bInstance.Method1();
        }
    }

    void WriteData()
    {
        lock (_aSync)
        {
            WriteToFile();
        }
    }
}

class B
{
    private object _bSync = new object();

    void Method1()
    {
        lock (_bSync)
        {
            // Have some code here which need to protect my
            // member variables.
            A.GetInstance.WriteData();
        }
    }

    void OneSecondTimerEvent()
    {
        lock (_bSync)
        {
            // Have some code here which need to protect my
            // member variables.
            A.GetInstance.WriteData();
        }
    }
}
```

How do I synchronize the `OneSecondTimerEvent()`, if One second timer gets triggered When the `A.Method1()` is being executed?

Comment: i would strongly advise against circular dependencies - _especially_ in multithreaded environments.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your code shows canonical example of [deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) - 2 resources waiting for each other to continue.

To resolve you can:

- manually order `lock` statements (i.e. B never takes additional locks if A already have lock),
- scope locks to only internal state of each class and never nest locks. In this case sometimes you'd need to copy state to call external methods.
- use other synchronization primitives/constructs that allow such nesting (i.e. Reader-Writer locks).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than try and solve this particular deadlock issue (which btw, is a classic result of locking things in an inconsistent order), I would strongly advise designing a better relationship between A and B. The fact you had to use a static instance to achieve a circular dependency should be a big clue you've done something wrong. Perhaps A and B should reference a 3rd class C, which is solely responsible for locking and writing the data? (Although it's difficult to say without a bit more context).